# Firebase Google Auth offline access_type to get a refresh_token

Tags: firebase, google-api, firebase-authentication, google-api-nodejs-client

We are using firebase with google authentication. We chose Google because our application makes Google API calls. 
We authorize these api calls with the access_token included in authorization payload that is returned from firebase. 
However, we are having trouble figuring out how to refresh the access_token after it expires.

We need a way to refresh this token without forcing the user to reauthorize. 
Ideally, I could request the offline access_type when requesting the firebase auth...
Is it possible to get an offline access_type Google oauth token through Firebase so that Google will return a refresh_token? 
With a refresh_token, I think I can grab a new access_token for api calls.

I was trying this but its definitely not supported:

```
const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar')
provider.setCustomParameters({ access_type: 'offline' }) // not work
firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not currently possible to get a Google OAuth refresh token via Firebase
Use separate code like in [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow) to get access token/refresh token, in addition to firebase auth.

Firebase auth's access_token/refresh_token does not work for Google APIs